# Why Doesn't This MySQL Query Return More Results?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is list an entry each time they have referred someone and that person is listed in the entries table as well.  3 different queries I have tried are:

```
SELECT a.ID,b.Email FROM Entries a 
INNER JOIN ReferAFriend b ON b.EntryID = a.ID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM Entries c ON b.Email = c.Email)
WHERE a.ID = 47667

SELECT a.ID,b.Email FROM Entries a 
INNER JOIN ReferAFriend b ON b.EntryID = a.ID AND b.Email IN (SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM Entries) 
WHERE a.ID = 47667

SELECT a.ID,b.Email FROM Entries a 
INNER JOIN ReferAFriend b ON b.EntryID = a.ID 
WHERE b.Email IN (SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM Entries) AND a.ID = 47667
```

The result of all 3 is just 1 entry.

If I do:

```
SELECT a.ID,b.Email FROM Entries a 
INNER JOIN ReferAFriend b ON b.EntryID = a.ID 
WHERE a.ID = 47667
```

I get a list of 20 entries because there are 20 referred friends, however there are only 4 that are in the entries database, which is what the other query is supposed to filter from these 20, but it only returns 1 result.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing parentheses in your first query (I'm assuming this is just a typo in your question). At first glance it looks ok... do you have any NULL email values?

Comment: Yeah sorry was a typo in the question.  All queries work, they just only return 1 value, when it should be returning 4.

Comment: If you just run `SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM Entries` what do you get?

Comment: I get all results.  All 20 of those emails returned in the 4th query there are returned.

Comment: So all of the queries work, except that they don't? ;)   If you can provide some sample data that shows the problem then maybe I can spot something, but the queries look ok at the moment.

Comment: haha they return results, but not the expected ones.  Turns out it was the a.ID = 47667 that was filtering more.  Using the Email in the entries worked fine.  Not sure why, but it works.

Comment: So is the issue resolved? Please mark your question somehow, if so (edit the question or post an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WHERE clause is filtering out the results to just one.  Changed that and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly re-structured...

```
SELECT DISTINCT STRAIGHT_JOIN 
      e1.ID,
      rf.Email 
   FROM
      Entries e1
         JOIN ReferAFriend rf
            on e1.ID = rf.EntryID
            JOIN Entries e2
               on rf.EMail = e2.EMail
   where
      e1.ID = 47667
```

Can you query and show the results of...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      e1.ID,
      rf.Email 
   FROM
      Entries e1
         JOIN ReferAFriend rf
            on e1.ID = rf.EntryID
   where
      e1.ID = 47667
```

Comment: Same result.  Only returns 1 instead of 4.

Comment: @fanfavorite, can you try the second query and see the results just from the simple join by referAFreind...